# Understanding the results of analyzing my application

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, analyzer, garbage

I have some memory problems, from another post I tried to analyze my project to understand my errors.... here are some things that I don't understand where's my error....

thanks

1: sqlite connection:
[sqlite connection http://grab.by/grabs/2125d36a8ec1fb0af1c813af33af5653.png](http://grab.by/grabs/2125d36a8ec1fb0af1c813af33af5653.png)

2: json converter:
[json converter http://grab.by/grabs/7b22080098c8931d7ef505a1eb7c087e.png](http://grab.by/grabs/7b22080098c8931d7ef505a1eb7c087e.png)

3: url connection:
[url connection http://grab.by/grabs/848a0942f69c91303347d08c64fb2fbb.png](http://grab.by/grabs/848a0942f69c91303347d08c64fb2fbb.png)

4: cell of uitableview:
[cell of uitableview http://grab.by/grabs/3917e88829bb6c956bb30445fc7bec20.png](http://grab.by/grabs/3917e88829bb6c956bb30445fc7bec20.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As stated you're assigning to `dbrc` without using it. You could just leave out the assignment if you're not going to use the error code.

   ```
   sqlite3_prepare_v2(...);
   ...
   while (sqlite3_step(...) == SQLITE_ROW) {
     ...
   ```
2. If the `for` loop above is not run (i.e. the regex fails to match), then `matchOk` will never be initialized, i.e. it contains garbage.

   ```
   NSString* matchOK = nil;
   int nM = 0;
   ...
   ```
3. You have `+alloc`ed a NSURLConnection but never store the result anywhere, thus to the analyzer there is no chance `-release`ing it afterwards. This causes a leak.
4. You have `+alloc`ed a TickerSessions without `-release`ing it.

Actually you could open the Build Results window to see what triggers the error.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeProjectManagement/art/analyzer_results_by_step.jpg

Answer (score 1):

1. You are assigning values to dbrc, but you are never using the assigned value. just get rid of that variable.
2. If the regular expression does not match or there's only one match, matchOk has an undetermined value, since the assignment will never be executed. Hence, the receiver for dataUsingEncoding message is garbage.
3. ReadType is of type that does automatic allocation during the assignment, most probably an NSNumber. You are never releasing that object.
4. You are explicitly allocating the tick value, but you are not releasing it before exiting the method scope.